# UMVUE help after finding complete and sufficient statistic

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ be a random sample from the distribution with pdf
$$f(x; \theta) = \theta x^{\theta – 1} I_{(0,1)}(x)$$ for $\theta > 0$

(a) Find the UMVUE for $\dfrac{1}{\theta}$.

(b) Find the UMVUE for $\left(\dfrac{\theta}{\theta + 1}\right)^n$.

I found the Fisher Information as $\dfrac{n}{\theta^2} = I(\theta)$ so the CRLB is $\dfrac{\theta^2}{n} $

I computed the joint pdf and rewrote it to be
$$f(\bar x; \theta) = I_{(0,1)}(x_i) \theta^n  e^{(\theta – 1)\sum_{i=0}^n \ln(x_i)} $$

Which would prove by exponential-family factorization that $\sum_{i=0}^n \ln(x_i)$ is a sufficient and complete statistic for the distribution right?

How do I find the UMVUE from here? I've seen a similar problem that relied on Pareto distribution but this is not Pareto since the exponent is positive right?

Comment: It's not Pareto since the support is bounded (and for other reasons).

The function $f(x) = \theta x^{\theta-1} I_{(\theta,1)}$ is not a probability density function since its integral is not $1.$ I suspect you misread $\theta x^{\theta-1} I_{(0,1)}.$

Comment: It would be an error to find something like $x_i,$ with the index $i,$ in the joint density function. For example,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^3 \ln(x_i) = \underbrace{\ln(x_1) + \ln(x_2) + \ln(x_3)}_\text{No “$i$'' appears here.}.
$$
But you have $I_{(\theta,1)}(x_i).$ In that expression, should $i$ be $1,$ or $2,$ or $3,$ or something else?

Comment: If $(\theta,1)$ were correct, then you would need to consider $$I_{(\theta,1)}(x_1)\cdots I_{(\theta,1)}(x_n) = I_{(\theta,1)}(\min_i x_i) = \underbrace{\min\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}}_\text{No “$i$'' appears here.}.$$ And in that case, that minimum would be a component of the sufficient statistic. But as it is either $x_1\cdots x_n$ or (equivalently) $\ln(x_1) + \cdots + \ln(x_n)$ is sufficient.

Comment: Notice that $\operatorname E(X_1\cdots X_n) = \left(\dfrac\theta{\theta+1}\right)^n,$ so you have a sufficient and unbiased estimator of $(\theta/(\theta+1))^n. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

This is a Beta distribution with the corrected support $(0,1)$.

Indeed as the density is a member of a full rank exponential family, $T=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\ln X_i$ is a complete sufficient statistic for this family of distributions. For the UMVUE you have Lehmann-Scheffe theorem, which says that an unbiased estimator based on a complete sufficient statistic is the minimum variance unbiased estimator.

It is easy to verify $E_{\theta}[-\ln X_i]=\frac1{\theta}$ for all $\theta>0$ via direct integration.

So you have $$E_{\theta}\left[-\frac Tn \right]=\frac1{\theta}\quad,\,\forall\,\theta$$

Again, as mentioned in comments, $$E_{\theta}\left[\prod_{i=1}^n X_i\right]=\left(E_{\theta}(X_1)\right)^n=\left(\frac{\theta}{1+\theta}\right)^n\quad,\,\forall\,\theta$$

Now as $T=\ln \left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\right)$ is complete sufficient, so is the one-to-one function $e^T=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$.

Hence conclude.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3030815/321264